# Pass JDK/JRE path into Grails command line execution

Tags: java, grails

Is there a way to pass a java/bin path name into grails on the command line, rather then having it always use what is in `JAVA_HOME`?  I have an instance where I share a build machine and need a 64-bit JDK, but the other group still needs to keep using the 32-bit JDK.

-------Solution-------------

`SET JAVA_HOME=C:\...`

`SET PATH=%JAVA_HOME%\bin;%PATH%`

Its crucial to place `%JAVA_HOME%` before the rest of the path, as windows will use the first path that contains the java executable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about setting `JAVA_HOME` for the current console/cmd before calling the Grails command?

```
set JAVA_HOME=path...
grails...
```

Setting the variable without exporting that will effect only the current console.

Comment: That makes perfect sense.  I'll accept your answer later today after testing it.

Comment: `SET JAVA_HOME=...` does update JAVA_HOME temporarily, but the Path variable that uses %JAVA_HOME% is not getting refreshed